# C#/EF - How to increment a non-ID number in a database and avoid duplicates when run at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Without marking the field as ID, how do I increment a number in the database and avoid duplicates, when somebody else increments it at the same time? (Using entity framework and C#.)

Example 1: The last number is 5. Client 1 fetches it from the database. Client 2 does the same. Client 1 increments it by one and inserts it back to the database. Last number is now 6. However, client 2 still thinks the last number is 5, so he inserts 6 again. The database is now [5,6,6]. Expected result is [5,6,7].

Example 2: there is a table of racers. Each racer has an ID, a name and a starting number (ID and starting number are not related). I want to add a new racer, with the starting number incremented by one, but with the guarantee, that if someone else adds another racer at the same time, the IDs will not be the same.

Is there any mechanism built in the language, or can this be only handeled at the database level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add concurrency check in EF. Add a new column, for example RowVersion in your entity, marked it with Timestamp attribute.

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

> The Timestamp attribute specifies that this column will be included in
>   the Where clause of Update and Delete commands sent to the database.
>   The attribute is called Timestamp because previous versions of SQL
>   Server used a SQL timestamp data type before the SQL rowversion
>   replaced it. The .Net type for rowversion is a byte array.

You can look [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for more information.